# Why is the old version of the module being used?

Tags: 7

I am creating a module, and I tried to update its files. I disabled the module, uninstalled it, deleted its files and then I put the new files in the sites/all/modules/mymodule. Then, I enabled my module.

The problem is that Drupal somehow is using the old version of my module rather than the new files I added. I cleared all the caches, from Drupal and manual from MySQL, but nothing changed.

Anyone ever had the same issue? Any ideas?

Comment: You might have your php code cached by OpCache or Zend.. I don't know barely anything about it but if your php.ini has a really long cache time for that, you'd feel like you're using old code I think.

Comment: I tried disabling OpCache without any success. It shows up as disabled but I see no difference in my module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When this has happened to me, it's because I have had the module in two locations and forgotten about it. Just search for the module's info file (using for example find - on Linux):

```
find /path/to/drupal_root -name mymodule.info
```

Comment: The server is configured by multiple persons and someone had it installed with a different directory name. I did that a minute before your answer and worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue once. The problem was that by mistake, I had the routing file with the name of other controller or some naming problem like that. Also I'd suggest to increase your module version number.